# CoreML load model saved with Keras 2

Tags: python, keras, ios11, coreml

Apple's new CoreML can work with models trained on popular framework. At least they say so at 18" in the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/703/). But in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml) it seems that concerning neural nets they only support Caffe and Keras 1.2.2 ([see code](https://github.com/gsabran/coremltools/blob/master/_deps/__init__.py#L55)), while Keras it on it 2.0 version and Tensorflow and Theano are quite popular in their own rights.

To get the conversion running with Keras 2, is there a better way than implementing the conversion myself? The Keras conversion code in the [coremltools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools) package is ~2000 lines longs and I don't have a deep knowledge of all Keras model representation so I really don't want to go that route.

I've tried converting a model saved with Keras 2 directly, but that doesn't work and fails with

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', u'gamma_initializer')
```

from `site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 326`

They also don't have a github for coremltools so it's hard to discuss this package in more details. I've uploaded a copy of the package: https://github.com/gsabran/coremltools

Comment: Apple staff have pointed out on the Apple development forums that Keras 2.0 support is coming.

Comment: That's good to hear! At WWDC?

Comment: No, in the forums at https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/system-frameworks/machine-learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keras 2.0 support is already there (released yesterday), with [coremltools v.0.4.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools)

Also, refer to newest comments on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79505)